# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker

When tried to execute native binary seeing following error

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./test": cannot find "libB.so.1" from verneed[2] in DT_NEEDED list for
```

`liB.so.1` is not a real shared library but symlink to `libA.so` as shown below

```
libB.so -> libs/libA.so
libB.so.1 -> libs/libA.so
libB.so.2 -> libs/libA.so
libB.so.2.1.0 -> libs/libA.so
```

`libA.so` has soname `libA.so`, used `readelf -d`

Executable `test` needs `libB.so.1`

I do not have shared library with soname `libB.so.1`

From the [page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-n-mr2-preview-1/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md) it appears that only libraries with matching `soname` are loaded.

If I need to have symlinks, is there a way to fix the issue. The test does not use `dlopen`